# NullpointerException in getview layoutinflator

Tags: android, baseadapter

Getting null pointer exception in `BaseAdapter` when displaying data in `CustomListview`

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ViewHolder holder = null;       

                 LayoutInflater layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

          convertView = layout.inflate(R.layout.player, null);           

          View vi = convertView;

            if (vi == null) {

                    holder = new ViewHolder();              

                    holder.tProduct = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product);
                    holder.tTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);            

                    convertView.setTag(holder);                     

            } else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }


            holder.tProduct.setText(description.get(position));
                holder.tTitle.setText(title.get(position));         

        return vi;
        }
```

Comment: post stacktrace first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do things like that

in your adapter create an `myInflater` variable like this

```
private LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

then in your code use that `myInflater` instead of the `getActivity()` you are using.

```
convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.player, null);
```

**EDIT**

For me that way of doing is the most efficient one as you only get the context one time. If you put it directly in the `getView` you'll access it each time `getView` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup_layout, null);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ViewHolder holder;       



      View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null) {
                  // here mContext is you got in constructor from activity
                LayoutInflater layout = mContext.getLayoutInflater();

                vi= layout.inflate(R.layout.player,parent,false);  

                holder = new ViewHolder();              

                holder.tProduct = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product);
                holder.tTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);            

                vi.setTag(holder);                     

        } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }


        holder.tProduct.setText(description.get(position));
        holder.tTitle.setText(title.get(position));         

    return vi;
    }
```